# Template parsing exception in thymeleaf while iterating Map

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, web, thymeleaf

i got some issue with my Spring boot project. When i try to open product cart page, i got exception `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "session.cart.getProducts()" (template: "cart" - line 14, col 11)`.
My cart.html page, where i try to get list:

```
</head>
<body class="body">
<div th:replace="header :: header_fragment"></div>
<th:block th:each="cartProduct : ${session.cart.getProducts()}">
  <div class="row p-2 bg-white border rounded mt-2">
    <div class="col-md-3 mt-1"><img class="img-fluid img-responsive rounded product-image" th:src="@{/${cartProduct.imagepath}}"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-1">
      <h5 th:text="${cartProduct.name}"></h5>
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="ratings mr-2"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></div>
        <span>310</span>
      </div>
      <p class="text-justify text-truncate para mb-0" th:text="${cartProduct.description}"><br><br></p>
    </div>
    <div class="align-items-center align-content-center col-md-3 border-left mt-1">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
        <h4 class="mr-1" th:text="${cartProduct.price} + '$'"></h4>
      </div>
      <h6 class="text-success">Available</h6>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-4">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" th:href="@{/cart/remove/{productid}(productid=${cartProduct.id})}">Delete form cart</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</th:block>
</body>
</html>
```

And my Cart object in session:

```
public class Cart {

    private final Map<Integer, Product> products;
    private float totalPrice;

    public Cart() {
        this.products = new HashMap<>();
        this.totalPrice = 0;
    }

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        products.put(product.getId(), product);
        totalPrice += product.getPrice();
    }

    public void removeProduct(int productId) {
        Product product = products.get(productId);
        products.remove(productId);
        totalPrice -= product.getPrice();
    }

    public static Cart checkCart(Product product, Cart cart){
        if (cart != null) {
            cart.addProduct(product);
        } else {
            cart = new Cart();
            cart.addProduct(product);
        }
        return cart;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return new ArrayList<>(products.values());
    }

    public float getTotalPrice() {
        return totalPrice;
    }

    public int getTotalSize() {
        return products.size();
    }

    public void setTotalPrice(float totalPrice) {
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
    }

    public void clear() {
        products.clear();
    }

}
```

Here i tried to get access to product list, where cart is object in session, which contains Map<Integer, Product>, and method getProducts() returns a transformed Map into ArrayList. I alse expect, that if my cart is null, there should be 0 iterations of loop. But as a result i got 500 error and a white page.
I also tries to write like this `session.cart.products` or `session.cart['products']` expecting that map will be automatically converted to List.

Comment: Try #ctx.session.car.products

Comment: What's your thymeleaf version ?

Comment: @JosselinBeaud'huy I use spring boot starter: spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf

Comment: @JosselinBeaud'huy #ctx.session.car.products not works

Comment: What's your spirngboot version ? Maybe a bug. I tried on my env and it works

Comment: My parent spring boot starter parent is 3.1.2

Comment: Can you post full html ?

Comment: Full cart.html without css and js links is presented in post. Or what do you mean? @JosselinBeaud'huy